# Compilers give different answers for Project Euler #22

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, cygwin

I'm doing Project Euler #22:

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>   file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>   into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>   each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>   list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

Compiling my code below with Cygwin's gcc-g++ compiler, the answer is `871129635`. But with Visual Studio 2008, the answer is correct, `871198282`. Why is this the case?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool strCmp(string x, string y) {
    if(x.compare(y) == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int getScore(string s) {
    int score = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        score += (((int) s.at(i)) - 64);
    return score;
}

int getTotalScore(vector<string> names) {
    int total = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        total += (getScore(names[i]) * (i+1));
    return total;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> names;
    ifstream namesFile("names.txt");

    char curChar;
    string curName = "";

    //get names from file
    if(namesFile.is_open()) {
        while(!namesFile.eof()) {
            curChar = namesFile.get();

            if(isalpha(curChar))
                curName.push_back(curChar);
            else {
                if(!curName.empty()) {//store finished name
                    names.push_back(curName);
                    curName.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    namesFile.close();

    //alphabetize
    sort(names.begin(), names.end(), strCmp);

    //count up name scores
    cout << getTotalScore(names) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your strCmp function, why do you compare the result of the compare function against -1?  There is no promise that compare will return a specific number, just that it will return a negative number if `lhs < rhs`.  And if that's what you're doing, checking if `lhs < rhs`, you don't need a special function, there is an overloaded `operator<` for strings, and sort will use that by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here:

```
if(x.compare(y) == -1)
```

You are assuming that `std::string::compare` will return `-1` for a less-than result, but it can in fact return any negative value. You can fix this by using `x.compare(y) < 0`, but it's better to just write `x<y`. In fact, you don't even need the `strCmp` function because the default behavior of `std::sort` is to compare the elements using `operator<`.